# Creating real-time thread on OSX

Tags: multithreading, macos, real-time, thread-priority, mach

I'm working on an OSX application that transmits data to a hardware device over USB serial. The hardware has a small serial buffer that is drained at a variable rate and should always stay non-empty.

We have a write loop in its own NSThread that checks if the hardware buffer is full, and if not, writes data until it is. The majority of loop iterations don't write anything and take almost no time, but they can occasionally take up to a couple milliseconds (as timed with CACurrentMediaTime). The thread sleeps for 100ns after each iteration. (I know that sleep time seems insanely short, but if we bump it up, the hardware starts getting data-starved.)

This works well much of the time. However, if the main thread or another application starts doing something processor-intensive, the write thread slows down and isn't able to stream data fast enough to keep the device's queue from emptying.

So, we'd like to make the serial write thread real-time. I read [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/conceptual/kernelprogramming/scheduler/scheduler.html) on requesting real-time scheduling through the Mach API, then tried to adapt the code snippet from SetPriorityRealtimeAudio(mach_port_t mach_thread_id) in the [Chromium source](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/base/threading/platform_thread_mac.mm).

However, this isn't working - the application remains just as susceptible to serial communication slowdowns. Any ideas? I'm not sure if I need to change the write thread's behavior, or if I'm passing in the wrong thread policy parameters, or both. I experimented with various period/computation/constraint values, and with forcing a more consistent duty cycle (write for 100ns max and then sleep for 100ns) but no luck.

A related question: How can I check the thread's priority directly, and/or tell if it's starting off as real-time and then being demoted vs not being promoted to begin with? Right now I'm just making inferences from the hardware performance, so it's hard to tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: The 'USB serial' driver does not interrupt upon 'TxEmpty', so allowing a non-polling interface?  If not, it sucks.

Comment: It's a multi-threaded OS with a scheduler that's supposed to be doing this. Can you explain a little more about why this is such a problem (are you running a life-critical medical device?), and give some numbers of the range of speeds you're experiencing, as well as some details about the environment (other stuff running on the machine)? Have you troubleshot the cause of the variability, or are you trying to go straight for forcing a thread that is real-time/high priority? Apps on multi-threaded OSes generally need to play nice and must consider the OS the arbiter of scheduling.

Comment: @jefflunt yeah - sounds like some nasty I/O polling - the very thing that modern, preemptive multitaskers were designed to avoid.

Comment: The app talks to a stepper motor driver board. If the driver board runs out of data, it can't do optimal motion planning, and the motors stutter and take dramatically longer to complete the motion sequence. This makes our users unhappy. I understand the general point about playing nice on multi-threaded OSs. This data streaming is associated with cancelable, time-limited, user-initiated actions that users expect to run at high priority.

Comment: From the Apple docs link:  "The kernel will make every effort to honor the [real-time thread priority] request, but since this is soft real-time, it cannot be guaranteed."   (in other words, non-real-time behavior under load is just a fact of life under MacOS/X; the only way to completely avoid it would be to avoid high load, or switch to a hard real-time OS)

Comment: I know it can't be guaranteed and the problem will probably never go away completely, but I still want to make the request in a way that maximizes its chances of being honored at least some of the time.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to move the thread of execution that requires the highest priority into a separate process.  Apple often does this for realtime processes such as driving the built-in camera.  Depending on what versions of the OS you are targeting you can use Distributed Objects (predecessor to XPC) or XPC.

You can also roll your own RPC mechanism and use standard Unix fork techniques to create a separate child process.  Since your main app is the owner of the child process, you should also be able to set the scheduling priority of the process in addition to the individual thread priority within the process.

As I edit this post, I have a WWDC video playing in the background and also started a QuickTime Movie Recording task.  As you can see, the real-time aspects of both those apps are running in separate XPC processes:

```
ps -ax | grep Video
 1933 ??         0:00.08 /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/VTDecoderXPCService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/VTDecoderXPCService
 2332 ??         0:08.94 /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/VTDecoderXPCService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/VTDecoderXPCService
```

[XPC Services at developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)

[Distributed Objects at developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Communication.html)